# Query multiple lists in one go

Tags: c#, linq

I have a series of lists:

```
List<foo> spamSpamAndSpam;
List<foo> spamSpamSpamSausageEggsAndSpam;
List<foo> spamSpamSpamSausageEggsBaconAndSpam;
List<foo> spamSpamSpamSpamSpamWithoutSpam;
List<foo> spamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamLovelySpamWonderfulSpam;
```

I also have a series of values I'm looking for in a property of `foo`:

```
List<string> Brian= new List<string>();
Brian.Add("Always");
Brian.Add("Look");
Brian.Add("On");
Brian.Add("The");
Brian.Add("Bright");
Brian.Add("Side");
Brian.Add("Of");
Brian.Add("Life");
```

I'm catching the references to all the `foo`'ses in which a a given property (say, `bar`) has a value contained in latter list. I'm doing it like this:

```
func<foo, bool> deadParrot = x => Brian.Contains(x.bar);

IEnumerable<foo> okLumberjacks = spamSpamAndSpam.Where(deadParrot);
okLumberjacks = okLumberjacks.Concat(
    spamSpamSpamSpamSausageEggsAndSpam.Where(deadParrot));

// And so on, concatenating the results of Where() from every list of <foo>.
```

I need every `foo` that has matched the filtering function in a single `IEnumerable<foo>` so that I can call a method in all of them in one go, like this:

```
foreach (foo incontinentRunner in okLumberjacks)
{
    incontinentRunner.SillyWalk();
}
```

So my question is... Is there a way to gather every `foo` in a single collection without having to resort to something like:

```
ni = ni.Concat(someList.Where(filter));
```

I mean, is there some more elegant way to do something like this with Linq? I'm looking for something like:

```
okLumberjacks = spamSpamAndSpam.
    And(spamSpamSpamSausageEggsAndSpam).
    And(spamSpamSpamSausageEggsBaconAndSpam) /* etc */ .Where(deadParrot);
```

Or even better:

```
okLumberjacks = spanishInquisition.Where(deadParrot);
// Where the type of spanishInquisition is List<List<foo>>.
```

I don't want to modify the original lists of `foo` because I need them as they are for another operation later on in the code.

Comment: All of the `OfType` calls in your code do nothing; you already have an `IEnumerable` of the type specified, so it's just a noop.

Comment: @Servy good point. But I'm using Sharepoint... None of its collection classes implement `IEnumerable<T>`, nor expose a `Where` extension method, but they all expose `OfType`, and I'm new to Linq. I'm editing the question to remove `OfType`.

Comment: +1 for more Monty Python references than I thought possible in a SO question.

Comment: In your example you're calling it on `List<T>` objects, which all implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  If the objects themselves aren't lists, but are in fact some other collection types that implement `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` then using `OfType` is appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a list of lists, and then just flatten it:

```
List<List<foo>> lists = new List<List<foo>>()
{
    spamSpamAndSpam,
    spamSpamSpamSausageEggsAndSpam,
    //etc.
};

IEnumerable<foo> items = lists.SelectMany(item => item);
//do stuff with items.
```

Comment: Nice. This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Best I can think of would be something like:

```
var everything = spam1.Concat(spam2).Concat(spam3);
var itemsIWant = everything.Where(x => Brian.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Rather than nesting the `Concat` operations you can chain them for easier syntax: `first.Concat(second).Concat(third).Concat(fourth);`

Comment: @Servy: Thanks ... knew something looked weird.

Comment: I don't know why I kept from trying that... I thought it would change the original lists, but I just tested and I see it doesn't. +1.

Comment: @Renan `AddRange` is the equivalent operator for `List` that's mutating.

Answer (score 1):

Does Union() resolve your problem?

```
        List<foo> spamSpamAndSpam;
        List<foo> spamSpamSpamSausageEggsAndSpam;
        List<foo> spamSpamSpamSausageEggsBaconAndSpam;
        List<foo> spamSpamSpamSpamSpamWithoutSpam;
        List<foo> spamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamLovelySpamWonderfulSpam;

        var x = spamSpamAndSpam
            .Union(spamSpamSpamSausageEggsAndSpam)
            .Union(spamSpamSpamSausageEggsBaconAndSpam)
            .Union(spamSpamSpamSausageEggsBaconAndSpam)
            .Union(spamSpamSpamSpamSpamWithoutSpam)
            .Union(spamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamLovelySpamWonderfulSpam)
            .Where(x => ..... );
```

**NOTE:** as it was properly noted, [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) excludes duplicates from the return set. This is different behavior to the [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) method, which returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates. Since duplicate exclusion was not a requirement, Concat is probably better

Comment: Does too. Thanks, I'm learning a lot with this question. I'll reread the documentation for every extension method when I get home.

Comment: Union would remove duplicates, which he didn't state as an explicit goal.  And if there are no duplicates then you're wasting time/effort/memory checking for them.  `Concat` is virtually the same as `Union` but without the dup checking, and seems to be the more appropriate operator here.

Comment: @Servy good to know. But duplication is tested with the equality operator, right? So two objects with the same property values would still evaluate as distinct, right?

Comment: @Renan Equality will be determined through `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.  If you aren't overwriting the `IEquatable` interface or the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods (from object) then it will use a reference comparison, not a memberwise comparison.  If you overrode one of those, it does whatever you did there.

Comment: @galets Side note, you shouldn't phrase your answers in the form of a question.  If you're going to post your answer as an answer phrase it as one.